# Oracle SQL 11g date value being retrieved as dd/mm/00yy instead of dd/mm/yy

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle11g

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (Customer_Id number PRIMARY KEY, First_Name varchar2(20), Last_Name varchar2(20), DOB date, Gender varchar2(1), PAN_No varchar2(20) UNIQUE);

INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(301, 'Robert', 'William', '05/10/86', 'M', 'PF58757');

SELECT * FROM Customer;
```

The DOB field shows up as 05/10/0086. I want it as 05/10/86.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` appears to be `DD/MM/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY`. When you insert a two-digit year, 86 is taken to mean 0086. You should specify the format in the insert:

```
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(301, 'Robert', 'William',
  TO_DATE('05/10/86', 'DD/MM/RR'), 'M', 'PF58757');
```

Or `'MM/DD/RR'`, depending on where you are.

The [RR date format element](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) was created to work around Y2K issues and it shouldn't really be necessary to use it amy more; your data should be supplied with a four-digit year. But even if your data can be changed to four-digits, you should still specify the format model anyway as another session might have something completely different, which could cause failures or data corruption. You should never rely on NLS settings.

[Trivial SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/440c0/1).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. As i entered different data it seems my NLS_DATE_FORMAT is MM/DD/YYYY                                 INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(301, 'Robert', 'William', TO_DATE('21/10/86','MM/DD/YY'), 'M', 'PQ56794');                                     I get an error saying invalid month. I wish to convert it to DD/MM/YY.

Comment: @MayankDeswal - that isn't your NLS_DATE_FORMAT, that's the format the date you're trying to insert is being supplied to you. But yes, if you have a date like 21/10/86, then you need to specify a match model in the `to_date()` call. Check the link about RR to see if that will be more suitable for you than YY. If that date is supposed to be 1986 (likely if it's a date of birth!) then you'd need to use RR, [otherwise it would be stored as 2086](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7782c/1).

Comment: ok I studied more about it and now i understand. Now i am able to input data in my format (DD/MM/RR). However one last thing is when i retrieve the data the format is MM/DD/RRRR. I am able to change the output format for sysdate using TO_CHAR() but I am not ablle to the same with hard coded date.

Comment: @MayankDeswal - why are you not able to `select to_char(dob, 'MM/DD/RR')`? It works exactly the same with any date field as it does with `sysdate`. If you don't use `to_char` then it will be displayed using your session's NLS_DATE_FORMAT again. Not really sure what you mean about a hard-coded date though.

Comment: Oh my bad. Yes i understand it now.You're correct. I just misunderstood something. I was format output inside INSERT whereas I should have done it under SELECT. It works now. Thanks Alex